# Redirection issue in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am having a problem with the following scenario

I am developing a chatting application wish a user can send a link in to a specific page like

`Hey check out my link www.link1.com`
what i am doing is using a reg-expression to detect the link and replace it by `<a href >`
this is the code i am using :

```
 public string ReplaceMsgHyperLinkIfExist(string msg)
    { 
        Regex r= new Regex(@"((?:(?:https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):(?://|\\\\)(?:www\.)?|www\.)[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+,\-=\\.&]+)");
        Match m = r.Match(msg);
        while (m.Success)
        {
          string val="<a href='"+m.Value+"' title='"+m.Value+"' >"+m.Value+"</a>";
          msg= msg.Replace(m.Value,val);
          m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

The problem is when the message is sent and the user click on it ,it's not redirecting properly,for example if the user send this message `hi www.google.com` in c# when the receiver click on it it redirect to `localhost:2525/www.google.com` (asp.net is considering the link as a subfolder and not as an actual path for another website what would be the solution for that ?

Comment: try to post an http://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Add `http://` or `https://` in front of every link when required

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the link starts with http:// or https:// otherwise the browser will think the link is relative.

Comment: This can go in comment. Not in answer. And some has already mentioned it in comment so nice copy paste.

Comment: @Mangesh Parte Check the time of my post and the comment next time. Nice reading.

Answer (score 0):

As Brain have already mention that make sure your link start with `http://` or `https://`.So Append `http://` or `https://` in your href tag attribute and also add `target="_blank"` property in your `<a>` tag.

Hope it will help you.